How to use insert_batch CI 3, but some param not need include on array?
I've form to insert data use insert_batch CI 3, my plan is use insert_batch to insert more data in one time and javascript to create dynamically the form. Below the code I've to try it.
Controller
public function insert_data()
{
    // Processing uploaded images
    $config['upload_path'] = 'training_assets/image_training/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1024'; // Maximum size allowed in KB
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    // Get the text field values
    $id_article = $this->input->post("id_article");
    $date = $this->input->post('date', TRUE);

    // Initialize an array to hold the batch data
    $data = array();

    foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $image) {
        $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $_FILES['images']['type'][$key];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $_FILES['images']['error'][$key];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $_FILES['images']['size'][$key];

        // Check if file upload is successful
        if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

            // Prepare row data for insertion
            $row_data = array(
                'question' => $this->input->post('question', TRUE)[$key],
                'a' => $this->input->post('a', TRUE)[$key],
                'b' => $this->input->post('b', TRUE)[$key],
                'c' => $this->input->post('c', TRUE)[$key],
                'd' => $this->input->post('d', TRUE)[$key],
                'key' => $this->input->post('key', TRUE)[$key],
                'img' => $upload_data['file_name']
            );

            // Add non-array data to each row
            $row_data['id_article'] = $id_article;
            $row_data['date'] = $date;

            // Add row data to the batch
            $data[] = $row_data;
        } else {
            echo "File upload failed for image $key.";
        }
    }

    // Insert data to database
    if (!empty($data)) {
        var_dump($data);
        //$this->db->insert_batch('tb_question', $data);
    } else {
        echo "No data to insert.";
    }

    //redirect("question");
}

HTML
...<label>Question</label>
          <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="question[]" placeholder="Enter question" />
<input readonly id="id_article" class="form-control" name="id_article" />
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="date" value="<?= date("Y/m/d"); ?>" />
  </div>...

I want to insert id_article and date but not insert into array, how to do it?, and is it possible?,
thank you

what is the output of var_dump($data); ?

got NULL for id_article and date

I think there was an issue issue on form post values are not receiving hate controller file, confirm $id_article = $this->input->post("id_article"); and $date = $this->input->post('date', TRUE); value comming or not
